# Isn't the amplification in amps always going towards infinity?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, feedback

In my textbook I have a scheme like this:
[image]

Which is trying to explain the principle of feedback. So the singal X1 is amplified into X2, part of X2 is returned and added with X1, which is again amplified and so on.... so wouldn't in the end both X1 and X2 become infinite, for a positive feedback?
And for a negative feedback they would become 0, with a similar logic.

Comment: What if \$\mu\$ is negative?

Comment: Key words: Positive vs. negative feedback.

Comment: X1 remains unaffected. Surely that is obvious?

Comment: What if -1 < μ < 1 and x1 became zero at some finite point?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition about positive feedback is correct.

For negative feedback, as mentioned elsewhere, \$ μ\$ becomes negative. Then the output adjusts so that the difference between the two terms becomes zero. For instance, if \$ μ\$ is -1, zero input occurs when the output equals the negative of the input, and the overall gain is -1.

Answer (score 0):

For positive feedback: Indeed it would want to reach infinity.

But in practice the range which X1 can have is limited by what amplifier A can make. If it is limited to -5 V to + 5 V then that's where it will get stuck, either at -5 V or + 5 V.

But positive feedback is usually not very useful for such systems. In most systems \$ μ\$ will have **negative** value and that means the system will have **negative feedback** and that will prevent the output signal from "running away".

Answer (score 0):

The most important value to asses is **loop-gain**. Using the same nomenclature as your block diagram the loop-gain is,

$$ T = \text{sign}(summer)\cdot  A \cdot \mu $$

There are two classes of systems/circuits that we often desire, namely, amplifiers or oscillators.

For an amplifier you must ensure that the loop-gain never exceed positive (+1). This criteria must be satisfied for all frequencies not just DC and you evaluate A as \$A(j\omega)\$ for any \$\omega\$.

For an oscillator to start-up you wish to have the loop-gain > 1, and then either by a circuit clipping or an AGC the steady state-state loop-gain should equal +1 at some frequency.

That's not to say an amplifier can't have positive feedback, but the loop-gain can not equal or exceed (+1). For example consider \$A = 10\$ and \$ \mu = 0.09\$, the transfer function of X2/X1 is,

$$ \dfrac{X_2}{X_1} = \dfrac{ 10 }{ 1 - (10)(0.09) } = 100 $$

This is referred to as regenerative feedback.

Comment: This is for a negative feedback?

Comment: The example I provided was for small positive feedback, where loopgain is still less than 1, note you are able to get a gain of 100x with a 10x amplifier, this was the basis of very early radio in some cases https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_circuit

Comment: Ok so suppose input is 10, then the output is 10*10=100, and the "return" is 100*0.09=9. New input is 10+9=19, output is 19*100=190, "return" is 190*0.09=17, new input is 17+10=27...What is wrong with my logic here? Seems like everything is just getting bigger

Comment: Your logic is correct, you can see the regenerative behavior, now continue to when the output equals 999.99. ( 10 + 999.99*0.09)*10 = 999.9910, the series converges to a gain of 100x

Answer (score -2):

What if your system is this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUBIAv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No explanation whatsoever, only kind of a counter question. Please explain your thoughts.

Comment: Just pointing out the "summer" (could be a Virtual GND node of OpAmp circuit) may have different polarity inputs, such as achieved with base and with emitter of bipolar providing the "summation".